# Parameter from URL into shell script

Tags: bash, apache, shell

How is it possible to get an URL parameter like **/?photo=1.png** into a shell script as a variable, running into a cgi-bin container on apache?

**Edit**
Iam generating a list of all files in a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo 

for file in /var/www/html/export/tui/*;
    do
        echo "<a href='/cgi-bin/test.cgi?file="${file: -27}"'>"${file: -27}"</a><br>";
done;
```

Now, i want to give the file name as a parameter into a second script, who needs this for reading it.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want to do it? a sample input with an expected output.

Comment: How do your file look like? give one such file-name?

Comment: I have no idea how is it possible to get the URL parameter into a shell script as a variable?

Comment: How does your file name look like?

Comment: my file name looks like "test.cgi"

Comment: Provide a valid input and output required. Your current information is not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution who take the URL parameter and give it into my script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo

function cgi_decodevar()
{
    [ $# -ne 1 ] && return
    local v t h

    t="${1//+/ }%%"
    while [ ${#t} -gt 0 -a "${t}" != "%" ]; do
        v="${v}${t%%\%*}" # digest up to the first %
        t="${t#*%}"       # remove digested part

        if [ ${#t} -gt 0 -a "${t}" != "%" ]; then
            h=${t:0:2} 
            t="${t:2}" 
            v="${v}"`echo -e \\\\x${h}` 
        fi
    done

    echo "${v}"
    return
}


function cgi_getvars()
{
    [ $# -lt 2 ] && return
    local q p k v s

    case $1 in
        GET)
            [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING}&"
            ;;
        POST)
            cgi_get_POST_vars
            [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING_POST}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING_POST}&"
            ;;
        BOTH)
            [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING}&"
            cgi_get_POST_vars
            [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING_POST}" ] && q="${q}${QUERY_STRING_POST}&"
            ;;
    esac
    shift
    s=" $* "

    while [ ! -z "$q" ]; do
        p="${q%%&*}"  
        k="${p%%=*}"  
        v="${p#*=}"   
        q="${q#$p&*}" 

        [ "$1" = "ALL" -o "${s/ $k /}" != "$s" ] && \
            export "$k"="`cgi_decodevar \"$v\"`"
    done
    return
}

cgi_getvars BOTH ALL


echo $foo
```